# Convert SSRS 2005 Report stream into a word document using C#

Tags: c#, reporting-services

Is it possible to convert the stream of SSRS 2005 report into word?
SSRS 2005 doesn't provide word export option.
How can we achieve that?

Regards
Sarayu

Answer (score 1):

By writing a SSRS extension for the Word format.

http://www.aspose.com/documentation/ssrs-rendering-extensions/aspose.words-for-reporting-services/index.html

http://jagbarcelo.blogspot.com/2006/07/reporting-services-ms-word-format-doc.html

Answer (score 1):

Our Data Dynamics Reports product will load RDL from a stream and process it natively (no dependency on SSRS, no conversion) and includes a word rendering extension. It costs only a couple hu dred more than the third party word render extension mentioned by others and includes may added features. For more about the differences and similarities with Data Dynamics Reports and SSRS see [this article](http://www.datadynamics.com/Products/Compare/CompareSQLServerReportingServices.aspx).